# using Authentication Provider without using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security 5.7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Now I am trying to implement spring security authentication provider for my spring boot spring security project. So previously we were able to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in our Security config file to customize the http and `HttpSecurity http` and `AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth` by overriding `configure`.

But now (Spring Security 5.7.0) WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  got deprecated and I am following WebSecurityCustomizer method like the following,

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig{

 @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/users/getUser");
    }

}
```

So Here using WebSecurityCustomizer  , how can I use authentication provider functionality in my ReST API ? Can anyone guide me to solve this issue or kindly suggest updated documentation for refer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the `WebSecurityCustomizer` is the bean that you want to use in this case. I guess that what you are trying to do is to configure a `SecurityFilterChain`, like so:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Anyways, it is not recommended to disable Spring Security in a certain endpoint, the alternative is to use `authorizeHttpRequests.antMatchers("/my-endpoint").permitAll()` if you don't want security on that endpoint.

About the `AuthenticationProvider` and `AuthenticationManager`, [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) can help you with questions that you may have.

> **Global AuthenticationManager**
> To create an AuthenticationManager that is available to the entire
> application you can simply register the AuthenticationManager as a @Bean.

> **Local AuthenticationManager**
> In Spring Security 5.6 we introduced the method HttpSecurity#authenticationManager that overrides the default AuthenticationManager for a specific SecurityFilterChain.
> Below is an example configuration that sets a custom AuthenticationManager as the default:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .authenticationManager(new CustomAuthenticationManager());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you kindly point me to spring-security documentation section stating that "it is not recommended to disable Spring Security in a certain endpoint, the alternative is to use (...).permitAll()"? I found them not being equivalent, permitAll somehow skips only the authorization step, causing weird behaviours with authentication.

Comment: The [api doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring()) says that if it’s a dynamic request you should consider mapping the request to allow all users instead. Additionally, in Spring Security 6 you can even extend that to static resources since Spring Security improved the [http session access](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6125)